# What is the opposite of dput() in R?

Tags: r, eval

I have a function which for some reason returns a a set of characters in the same way dput() does, i.e as "c("A","B","C")". How do get it back to a character vector. i.e [1] "A" "B" "C"

See the following toy example

```
x = c("A", "B", "C")
dpx = dput(x)
```

How do I get dpx back to x again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
eval(parse(text = "c(\"A\",\"B\",\"C\")"))
```

but it is probably a better idea to fix the output of that function.

Comment: Probably right there with using `assign` to create groups of objects in a `for` loop...:)